# Create new txt files from each line of a txt file

Tags: php, file-io

I have a various txt files like ex: dictionary , each new line is term and then description. pipe delimited.

I have wrote simple script that actually reads each line and then creates (fwrite) new txt file named after term and description as a text of that file.

It works but I'm wondering if there is a better approach, one that takes special characters into account, buffer perhaps, Not sure where to start.

```
$file = fopen("test.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
//  Output a line of the file until the end is reached
while(!feof($file))
{
    $line = fgets($file);

    // making all lowercase - optional
    $line = strtolower($line);

    // take the first value before delimiter
    $var = substr( $line, 0, strpos( $line, '|' ) );

    // remove some characters - optional ( depends on a file structure and contents )
    $var = str_replace("-", "", $var);

    // what txt should be written into a each new file
    $txt = str_replace("|", "", $line);

    // name the file 
    $myfile = fopen("$var.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

    // write
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);

    //close each
    fclose($myfile);

}

//close
fclose($file);
```

UPDATE

```
$file = fopen("test.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
//  Output a line of the file until the end is reached
while(!feof($file))
    {
        $line = fgets($file);

        // @sorak fix
        $line = fgets($file);
        $name = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/', '', 
          explode('|', $line)[0]);

        // making it lowercase - optional for each
        $line = strtolower($line);
        $name = strtolower($name);

        // what txt should be written into a each new file
        $txt = str_replace("|", " ", $line);

        // name the file 
        $myfile = fopen("$name.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

        // write
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);

        // action echo
        echo "$myfile - $name - $txt </br>";

        //close each
        fclose($myfile);

    }

//close
fclose($file);
```

Since last update contained some duplicate code lines/bugs that caused skipping every other line :) I'm posting new fixed and bit upgraded version.

```
// this utility is for creating multiple names.txt files from separate lines in original.txt file
// format for original file is: is name|text

// increase memory limit to 32M
ini_set('memory_limit','32M');

// increase 1440 seconds = 24 minutes
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1440);

$file = fopen("original.txt", "r");
if ($file) {
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {

        // @sorak fix
        //$line = fgets($file);
        $name = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/', '', 
          explode('|', $line)[0]);

        // making it lowercase - optional for each
        $line = strtolower($line);
        $name = strtolower($name);
        $filename = $name . ".txt";

        // what text should be written into a each new file
        // change pipe separator if needed
        $txt = str_replace("|", " ", $line);

        // set values 
        $myfile = fopen($filename, "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $dir = "/example.com/could_be_dynamic_folder_name";

        // write
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        // chmod($dir,0777); optional if creation of dir is from GET/other value and not in the same parent

        // action echo
        echo "$myfile </br>";
        echo "$dir/$filename </br>";
        echo "$txt </br></br>";

        // chmod
        chmod($dir,0777);
        chmod("$dir/$filename",0666); // remember to set this script to 0666 

    }

    fclose($file);

} else {

    // error echo
    echo "something went wrong, error";

}
```

Works like a charm now. Case closed.

Comment: You could use `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` for file reading and writing. These might cause issues with really large files, but they are generally easier to use and don't require much code.

Comment: learn `explode`, it will save a bit of time.

Comment: @ Jordi Kroon , please be more descriptive, show an fit example otherwise

Comment: @ Forbs, Yes, @sorak answer excellent example of explode, but thx for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$line = fgets($file);
$name = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/', '', 
            explode('|', $line)[0]);
```

Explode makes splitting up the string easier, and with the `[0]` we grab the first piece. That `preg_replace` instruction just removes all characters that aren't letters or numbers.

Comment: After what this code replaces, your existing logic is suitable and reasonably minimal. That is, you're doing it right, and it doesn't get much better. What else would you like this code to do?

Comment: Actually @sorak, that's about it. Thank You. I have sufficient PHP just for my own small projects purposes, and I use explode in my other small scripts,  just didn't clicked in my head, I guess :)

Comment: I just added an Update of fully working script to my question, just in case someone will ever needed such a script. :)